# Extjs 4 to 6 migration classes

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs6, extjs6-classic

We have js files writen in Extjs 4. I have to migrate theese to Extjs 6. Almost everything is fine, but when we `create` own classes (extended extjs classes), we have a problem. (Unfortunately there's no mvc, just classes and `create`). In the ext-all-debug:

```
create: function(config, defaultType) {
    if (typeof config === 'string') {
        return Ext.widget(config);
    }
    if (config.isComponent) {
        return config;
    }
    if ('xclass' in config) { // **config is true**
        return Ext.create(config.xclass, config);
    }
    return Ext.widget(config.xtype || defaultType, config);
},
```

The `config` is `true` except an object, and we got the following error message in the console: *"Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'xclass' in true"*

[image]

What is the problem with our classes or creating?

This is a class:

```
Ext.define("My.component.TrunkListGrid", { 

    extend: "My.component.Grid", 

    // config

    viewConfig: {
        enableTextSelection: true
    },

    initComponent: function () {

        // ...

        Ext.apply(this, {
            // ...          
        });

        this.callParent();

        this.addListener('render', function () {
            // ...
        }, this);

    }

});
```

This is a create:

```
var g = Ext.create('My.component.TrunkListGrid', {
    // config
});
```

I think, I have to call something another way...

Comment: Please show the code of your failing class. Nearly every browser gives you a full stack trace, please attach that to your question.

Comment: Every own class fails I think. :(

Comment: Well, please show some sample Ext.create then.

Comment: Please show your `dockedItems` config, which seems to be `true` or an array containing at least one value `true`.

Comment: `tbar: this.showTbar ? {items: tbItems} : undefined,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oah, I found it! We used the `buttons: true` in the config